# Replace .vmdk for VirtualBox in bash?

Tags: scripting, virtualbox

So I have a external SATA adapter and a VirtualBox Windows 10 VM.  I regularly swap in and out hdds that I want the VM to be able to access.  Now I can create the vmdk with no issue with `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename VMShare/external.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/$part`.

Now I thought I'd be clever and write a script that just replaces each instance of `external.vmdk` when I swap in and out a new hdd.  VirtualBox does not like this, and reports that the UUID `{#}` of the medium `~/VMShare/external.vmdk` does not match the value `{#}` stored in the media registry (`~/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml`).

Now I've tried messing with the xml files to match up the UUIDs but with no luck.  I've also tried `VBoxManage storageattach Windows --storagectl "SATA" --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd --medium none` to wipe that spot clear, then reload the vmdk, but I get the same error.  I suspect I need to refresh something somehow, but I'm really not sure which setting I need to hit next.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in the Arch wiki!

The specific command was `VBoxManage closemedium disk VMShare/external.vmdk`

Full code:

```
# remove old vmdk
echo "Removing old"
eval "VBoxManage storageattach Windows --storagectl "SATA" --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd --medium none"
eval "VBoxManage closemedium disk VMShare/external.vmdk"
eval "rm VMShare/external.vmdk"

# create new vmdk and add it
echo "Creating new"
eval "VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename VMShare/external.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/$part"
eval "VBoxManage storageattach Windows --storagectl "SATA" --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd --medium VMShare/external.vmdk"
```